# How to prevent Flash from blurring an image after zooming with the `z` property?

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming

I'm currently testing various ways to zoom images (or rather, whole DisplayList hierarchies). Using `scaleX` and `scaleY` works quite well, but when I use the `z` property to zoom the image (by placing it further away) the image gets blurred when returning to `z=0`.

The image is put in a `Sprite` ("groundLayer") and that `Sprite` itself is put in another `Sprite` ("zoomLayer"). Whenever I'm zooming I'm manipulating properties of the "zoomLayer" only.

This image was taken right after returning `scaleX` and `scaleY` back to `1.0`:
[image: no blurring]

This image was taken right after returning `z` back to `0.0`:
[image: slight blurring]

I've tried searching for information about this phenomena but couldn't really find anything useful. Can anyone explain what's happening there? Why is Flash blurring the image after manipulating the `z`property? Is there a way to prevent that (well, other than obviously leaving `z` alone)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

whenever you introduce the 3D you are operating under a different rendering engine, it makes things blurry as hell and really should be avoided if possible. To counteract the problem when returning to its original size you need to set `mc.transform.matrix3D = null;` then it will return to 2D space and be rendered normally again.
if you are wanting to do it while at a different point then have a look through [exampes here](http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/48-native-3d-transformations-issues-objects-get-blurry-slightly-bigger-and-have-wrong-depth.html)to try and pick out something more useful to you:

I see no reason in this example why you would prefer to be using the 3d engine rather than the 2d scale.

Comment: +1 and accepted, very good answer! Thanks also for the link, I have searched Google and Bing up and down and haven't found anything helpful related to the issue. The reason why I'm dealing with this is that another team here was using the z property as a zoom mechanism and got the usual blur. I'll recommend them to use `scaleX` and `scaleY` instead. :)

Comment: interesting.  i wonder if the same remedy is required while using the new Stage3D API in FP11?